# How to insert date/time in notepad++ 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, notepad++, date-time

Old question are about **32-bit**. And they are working on 32-bit.

But in **64-bit notepad++** there are much less working add-ons, so the fastest solution: open simple notepad, press <kbd>F5</kbd> and copy date-time from there.

Is there any option to add date-time without leaving the notepad++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Notepad++ 8.1.5, you can insert a custom date/time format using `Edit/Insert/Date Time (customized)`. You can customize it in `Settings/Preferences/Multi-Instance & Date`.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is my set of [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.org) macros which insert timestamps in various formats not only in N++ but across the entire OS. You can adjust the format string as you need.

```
#F2::   ;Date/time with safe characters for use in filenames
    FormatTime, TimeString,, yyyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss
    Send %TimeString%
    Return

#F3::   ;Short date
    FormatTime, TimeString,, yyyyy-MM-dd
    Send %TimeString%
    Return

#F4::   ;Shortest possible date
    FormatTime, TimeString,, yyMMdd
    Send %TimeString%
    Return

#F5::   ;Date/time
    FormatTime, TimeString,, yyyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    Send %TimeString%
    Return
```

So this way <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> inserts timestamp containing date and time.

You can limit the scope only to Notepad++ by using [#IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm) directive, just *above* the macros. I am using this one:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad\+\+
```

Note: Window title match string used above relies on the following [SetTitleMatchMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) setting:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
```

but if you have different mode, your title used with `#IfWinActive` directive may vary. See the above links.

Comment: I think it will be OK working solution. But still I believe there is an option inside the N++.

Comment: @XuMuK – yes I respect that approach. On the other hand, inserting dates is useful across all applications so waiting until someone writes a plugin only for N++ when for much lower cost and time you can provide yourself with better solution, i.e. fully configurable according to your exact needs... I am not sure whether waiting for more limited N++-only plugin makes sense.

Comment: thank you @miroxlav, I used this solution ,
here is a HelloWorld for AutoHotKey that can helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcgQlGeaPHw

Answer (score 2):

A 64-bit plug-in from Don Ho includes inserting date/time into Notepad++. It also provides an easy mechanism for creating your own Notepad++ plug-ins.
[Notepad++ PlugInDemo v3.1](https://github.com/npp-plugins/plugindemo/releases/tag/3.1)

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution for people who want less fuss:

I solved this with a macro that allows me to use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to insert the long form of date and time at cursor position.

---

Here are the steps

In Notepad++

- Macro/Start Recording
- Edit/Insert/Date Time (long)
- Macro/Stop Recording
- Macro/Save current recorded macro

  (choose the desired key command from the popup dialog box, and give your macro a name -- I called mine "INSERT DATE TIME CAROLYN" so that I would remember that I created it)

EXIT NOTEPAD++ COMPLETELY to cause it to write the macro to the shortcuts.xml file. If you skip this step, the macro will be lost in the event, say, that Windows unexpectedly shuts down for an update.

The Macro menu will now display the name of your macro along with the key command that you chose.

You can run the macro using your mouse to click Macro/INSERT DATE TIME, or using the key command displayed under the Macro/ menu

---

Test:

Place your cursor where you want the stamp applied, hit your key combination.

The end. Easy.

Notepad++ has been good about saving all of my customizations, so I expect that when there is an update, this macro will be saved for me.

---

### Update 2023-01-06:

Currently, Notepad++ requires that it be exited for the macro to be saved permanently. Frustratingly, whenever Windows shut itself down for an update, when I re-opened Notepad++, my macro was no longer available. I figured out the problem by reading between the lines on this page: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/macros/ Here we see that

> Notepad++ writes the configuration files (including the macros) when it exits, which means that after you save your macro, your new macro will not be written to the shortcuts.xml configuration file until Notepad++ exits. Thus, if you open shortcuts.xml after saving the macro but before exiting Notepad++, you will not be able to see your new macro yet.

So I think what was happening was that Notepad++ did not consider these Windows shutdowns to be a proper exiting of its program, which would have triggered the writing of the macro to the shortcuts.xml file, so the macro was simply lost. When I figured this out, I added the step Exit Notepad++; the next time I opened NP++, the macro was there.

Comment: no need to record a macro just for inserting date time. There's already an entry for it in the shortcut mapper

Comment: Thanks @phuclv! It's about the same amount of effort as making a macro. In both cases, the magic is to know that the method exists.

Answer (score 1):

The feature has already been built into Notepad++. Just go to *Edit > Insert > Date Time ...* No need for any 3<sup>rd</sup> party add-ons

If you want to add a shortcut just go to *Settings > Shortcut Mapper...* and search for `date`

[image: Notepad++]

[image]