# How to insert current date and time in Notepadqq (with a custom keyboard shortcut)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Title says it all.

*<sub>(I appreciate that there may be **more than one** way of doing this and **assume that it is be possible** to do this in **Notepadqq** in the first place)</sub>*

---

Related / see also:

- https://notepadqq.com/s/
- https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq
- [How to insert date/time in notepad++ 64bit](https://superuser.com/questions/1278798/how-to-insert-date-time-in-notepad-64bit)

---

**Update (Apr 2019):**

More relevant link(s):

- **https://askubuntu.com/questions/676422/inserting-text-with-a-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ubuntu**
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/237209/how-to-create-option-to-insert-time-stamp

<sub>*(Compare also with [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193411/hot-key-to-type-todays-date) and/or [this](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Beginners-Guide), linked here for reference / "completeness": both can safely be ignored as the more general question has these covered / "included".)*</sub>

Comment: -1 ? Care to comment?

Comment: perhaps because it seems more like an ad for Notepadqq, may be! I can be wrong though.

Comment: IMHO, your 3rd link answers your need.. just need to change the `#IfWinActive` part from notepad++ to notepadqq instead.